# Nested Threads For Nested Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, async-await, nested

I currently using **async/await** method and that's helpful with **https requests** but doesn't help with **synchronous code**.

What can I do to **improve performance** in that case?

Can I use something like nested **worker threads**?

I can use worker threads in the last functions but I want to be able to use them in **nested mode**!

Is it possible to do something like that in **javascript/node.js** or I have to switch **language/platform**!?

*Code example:*

```
(async(){
    /*Some code*/
    let Items=[]; //Long array
    for(let Item in Items){
        (async(){
            /*Some code*/
            let Items=[]; //Long array
            for(let Item in Items){
                (async(){
                    //And so on ...
                })();
            }
            /*Wait until all functions done*/
            /*Some code*/
        })();
    }
    /*Wait until all functions done*/
    /*Some code*/
})();
```

**Best answer until now:**
Using shared resources between threads, Because threads can't run in nested mode (making a tree/within each other)!

Comment: If you're doing long-running calculations that are using a lot of CPU, then you will want to get that out of the main thread.  You can either use workerThreads or spin up specialized child processes.  You can communicate results and work jobs to either the workerThread or the child process via nodejs built-in messaging.  FYI, `async` does not help at all with CPU-intensive calculations.

Comment: What do you mean by "nested"?

Comment: "*it was taking up to 2 days to calculate all that data*" - what calculations are you doing?

Comment: js is single threaded, but there is a module that offers you a falsy sansation of concurrency `npm install run-parallel`

Comment: @Ernesto Or code could use worker threads (which, uhh, can run on different host threads for true parallelism between each worker thread and the main application) while remaining inside the familiar async/await concurrency model..

Comment: _"some times it was taking up to 2 days to calculate all that data!"_ - what kind of data is it? 

Comment: Either a dup or a helpful read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974791/handle-long-running-processes-in-nodejs

Comment: @Ernesto, I am 100% sure that, OP asking for parallelism **not concurrency**! they are very different!

Comment: My data comes from stock market and that's not a massive data, Just list of symbols and their candlestick data, But I built an algorithm that does calculation in nested mode (that's how it works to calculate the performance of algorithm in specified amount of time) and that's why it some times takes of to 2 days (actually it can take infinite amount of time but I don't need that amount of calculations)!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, code *can* use something like Node.js [*Worker threads*](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) to allow parallelism for CPU-bound work.

> Workers (threads) are *useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations*. They do not help much with I/O-intensive work. The Node.js built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers can be.

The async concurrency model is still used and *each execution context is single-threaded*.

The worker threads are themselves running in separate execution contexts and, *conceptually in context of await (eg. of promise wrappers around the events), using worker threads is little different than using XHR to dispatch processing to remote compute servers*.

Unlike more direct multithreaded support in other languages, this also comes with the restriction that objects are not implicitly shared between the node app and any worker threads, as they are not shared in remote XHR work. Code will need to be written to appropriately divide data and join results or otherwise marshal through a shared resource (eg. filesystem or SharedArrayBuffer).

Comment: no, node is single threaded, workers are independent from one another. 
JS uses only one thread, each worker uses its own thread

Comment: Was that not covered by the answer in various forms, including “The async concurrency model is still used such that each execution context is single-threaded”?

Comment: then why did you start with `yes, code can use`.  I do not have time to read your essay

Comment: The question answered is “Can I use something like nested worker threads?” — and the answer is *yes, you can achieve CPU parallelism, fitting within the async/await model hinted at in the pseudo code*.

Comment: @Ernesto Why do you claim that node is single threaded when there are clearly multiple worker threads in one node process?